# Data validation/ avoiding multiplication errors

Tags: excel, validation, excel-2013

I'm working on a document to auto-populate cells when i type item codes into a box. I then want those boxes to calculate total costs based on each line. However, if no numbers are present a "0" shows in each field. I've tried eliminating those "0"s by using `=IF(A1*B1+0," ", A1*B1)`. However, since the blank space is no longer a numerical value, I can't sum all the columns.

[image: image description here]

Any advice on how to have blank cells when nothing present, but still have the final column find the total of each row?

I'm on excel 2013

Comment: Sum should skip any text, try `=SUM(R[-10]C:R[-1]C)`

Comment: How do you know what is causing the error? Have you tried the `Evaluate Formula` feature in excel to conclude that the non-numerical values or spaces are causing an issue? Also, which formula notation are you using, your question text indicates `A1` notation (i.e. `=IF(A1*B1+0," ", A1*B1)`) but the picture you have pasted shows `R1C1` notation! Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

There was a missing SUM function for adding up cells in row 3 & 4. I found it by using the Evaluate Formula and it showed me where the calculation was failing.

```
=IFERROR(SUM(R[-6]C:R[-1]C)+SUM(R[-10]C:R[-9]C),"ERROR")
```